# Is there a way to call resolve() on module.require in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

It seems that in Node.js **'require'** and **'module.require'** are not only separate objects but also different types of objects. 'require.resolve' exists but 'module.require.resolve' does not.

Is there any way to call resolve on module.require?

The reason I would like to do that is I would like to call **require.main.require.resolve()** to see what require.main.require 
resolves a given path to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I can find out to explain.

`require.main` gets you the module object for the script that was run first in this node.js process.

`require.main.require` gets you a function you could use to load scripts as if you were in that main script.

`require.main.require` does not have a `.resolve()` method.  While `require.main.require` does get you a require function, as you have found it is not the exact same object that you get when you are in a module itself.  It is just a function and appears to have none of the properties that the require object has in your own module.

The require object in your own module gets created by a special function called `makeRequireFunction()` in the loader (see [source code here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js#L14)).  That's where the other properties are added to it.  But, the `require.main.require` is the same as `process.mainModule` and is just the require function by itself, not that special object.

---

A work-around would be to export `resolve()` from your entry script then access that exported function from the other script.

In your main module, you could put this:

```
module.exports.resolve = require.resolve;
```

Then, you could access that elsewhere with:

```
require.main.exports.resolve(...);
```

Comment: That's a good trick.  Seeing it I think I could make it even simpler and in the main module say: module.r2 = require. That would store the module-specific require in addition to the standard module.require. Kind of convoluted but I'll give it a try. Thanks